# Erro android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: fs_promocoes

Tags: java, android

```
public class PromocaoDAO  {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "app_promocoes.db";
private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 2;

private static final String TABLE_PROMOCOES = "fs_promocoes";

public static final String PROMO_ID = "id";
public static final String PROMO_DESCRICAO = "descricao";
public static final String PROMO_STATUS = "status";
public static final String PROMO_INICIO = "inicio";
public static final String PROMO_TERMINO = "termino";

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String TABELA_PROMO =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_PROMOCOES + " (" +
                PROMO_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                PROMO_DESCRICAO + "," +
                PROMO_INICIO + "," +
                PROMO_TERMINO + "," +
                PROMO_STATUS + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + PROMO_ID +"));";


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABELA_PROMO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROMOCOES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public PromocaoDAO(Context ctx){
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public PromocaoDAO open() throws SQLException{
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    if(dbHelper != null){
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long inserirPromocao(String descricapo, String inicio, String termino){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PROMO_DESCRICAO, descricapo);
    values.put(PROMO_INICIO, inicio);
    values.put(PROMO_TERMINO, termino);
    values.put(PROMO_STATUS, 1);

    return db.insert(TABLE_PROMOCOES, null, values);
}

public Cursor buscarTodasPromocoes(){

    Cursor mCursor;
    mCursor = db.query(TABLE_PROMOCOES, new String[] {PROMO_DESCRICAO, PROMO_INICIO, PROMO_TERMINO},null,null,null,null,null);
    if (mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public void testeInsertPromocao(){
    inserirPromocao("PROMOCAO DE NATAL", "10/11/2016", "31/12/2016");
    inserirPromocao("PROMOCAO DE PESCOA", "10/11/2016", "31/12/2016");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece porque você adicionou uma nova tabela sem mudar a versão do banco.

Você pode desinstalar a aplicação e rodar de novo pra resolver ou somente mudar a versão do banco.

Mas como seu projeto deve estar em desenvolvimento ainda é aconselhável que você desinstale antes de rodar de novo,

Comment: Então Leonardo, eu já fiz isso. Mas continua apresentando o mesmo problema.

Comment: Você desinstalou a aplicação do device e rodou novamente?

Comment: Exato. Fiz isso e mudei a versão do banco também.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar que sempre caia no `onUpgrade`, faça um teste, inserindo uma condição que ocorra apenas se você fizer a troca da versão do Database (`VERSAO_BANCO`):

```
    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion){
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROMOCOES;
        database.execSQL(sql);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```